# Not able to receive UDP/IPv6 packets on secondary interface

Tags: c, udp, localhost, ipv6

I have the following C code for UDP server which would bind to the ipv6 address of the secondary interface tap0.

```
context_t *
new_context(const struct sockaddr *listen_addr, size_t addr_size) {
  context_t *c = malloc( sizeof( context_t ) );
  time_t now;
  int reuse = 1;

  if (!listen_addr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no listen address specified\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  srand( getpid() ^ time(&now) );

  if ( !c ) {
    perror("init: malloc:");
    return NULL;
  }

  memset(c, 0, sizeof( context_t ) );

  c->sockfd = socket(listen_addr->sa_family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if ( c->sockfd < 0 ) {
    perror("new_context: socket");
    goto onerror;
  }

  if ( setsockopt( c->sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse) ) < 0 )
    perror("setsockopt SO_REUSEADDR");

  if ( bind (c->sockfd, listen_addr, addr_size) < 0 ) {
    perror("new_context: bind");
    goto onerror;
  }

  return c;

 onerror:
  if ( c->sockfd >= 0 )
    close ( c->sockfd );
  free( c );
  return NULL;
}



context_t *
get_context(const char *ipaddress, const char *port, unsigned int  scopeId) {
  int s;
  context_t* ctx;
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *result, *rp;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Coap uses UDP */
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICHOST | AI_NUMERICSERV | AI_ALL;

  s = getaddrinfo(ipaddress, port, &hints, &result);
  if ( s != 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
    return NULL;
  } 

  /* iterate through results until success */
  for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
    ctx = new_context(rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);
    if (ctx) {
      if ( rp->ai_family == PF_INET6 ) {
         struct sockaddr_in6* pSadrIn6 = (struct sockaddr_in6*) rp->ai_addr;
         if ( pSadrIn6->sin6_scope_id == 0 ) {
            pSadrIn6->sin6_scope_id = scopeId;
         }  /* End IF the scope ID wasn't set. */
      }
      goto finish;
    }
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "no context available for interface '%s'\n", node);

 finish:
  freeaddrinfo(result);
  return ctx;
}
```

Device tap0 has following details:

```
tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ce:23:fc:81:7f:65  
          inet6 addr: fe80::cc23:fcff:fe81:7f65/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: aaaa::1/64 Scope:Global
```

I run the above code with the following command:

```
./server -A aaaa::1
```

But it's not able to listen to the messages coming to the address aaaa::1 on tap0. I can see the packets on the wireshark dump on tap0 interface. Interestingly, the server ran from the above command(and code) can receive the messages through the localhost. So, if I execute the following command, the server receives the messages:

```
nc -6 -vvv -u aaaa::1 61616 < /tmp/send_to_node_raw
```

The above command sending and reception is done through localhost.
Is there any way I can programatically receive UDP/IPv6 messages on secondary interfaces?

Comment: What's the `scopeId` you are setting? Is it `1` by any chance?

Comment: It's just one interface, really. And mind you, bind(2) "binds" to addresses, not interfaces, that is to say, packets with dst addr aaaa::1 will be received at most.

Comment: @Nikolai: I am setting scopeId as tap0.

Comment: http://silmor.de/59 -- this is an interesting link which explains how in IPv6, the packets addressed to all the local IPs(link scope and global) are lopped back to itself (device "lo"). This is done through the local routing table rules (seen through route -n -6). If I remove these rules, the packets start to go to the tap0 interface but their address is modified to a multicast address; that's where my case is resting right now.

Comment: Ah, I noticed you are actually playing around with CoAP, right?

Comment: @errordeveloper Yes, you guessed it right.

Comment: @AmitS, I am currently working on a CoAP lib also, but using Node.js. I have looked at libcoap, but it seems a bit odd to me. The cleanest C implementation I have seen so far is [ERBIUM](https://github.com/mkovatsc/SmartAppContiki/blob/master/apps/er-coap-07/er-coap-07.c), it has only a few Contiki/uIP specific things, I guess it can be ported quite quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be somewhere else. Using the code above I can successfully receive packets from another node using aaaa::1/64 and aaaa::2/64 as the local and remote addresses, respectively.

Try to bind to :: and see if it works that way. Also try to use netcat6 to bind to aaaa::1 and receive from another netcat6 instance.