# Linux C/C++ UDP server on the secondary network interface issue

Tags: c++, linux, server, udp, gateway

I have a problem receiving UDP packets on a Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, with 2 different network interfaces:
1. ethernet with 10.x.x.x IP
2. wifi with 192.168.x.x

The packets are arriving on the 2nd interface (wlan0), I can see them on wireshark/tcpdump, but no packet received by my udp server.

I also tried to bind to the wlan0 interface (`setsockopt(localSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...`, bind to 0.0.0.0, 192.168.x.x, but no luck.

Also, `netcat -4 -u -l 0.0.0.0 <port>` (as well as on 192.168.x.x) receives none.

The only way I managed to make it work is only I change the default gateway to the 192.168.x.y

routing table:

```
user@ubuntu-ws:/tmp$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.x.x.x        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         OpenWrt.lan     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
10.x.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.x.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

This seems to be somehow related to [Not able to receive UDP/IPv6 packets on secondary interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605240/not-able-to-receive-udp-ipv6-packets-on-secondary-interface) but this time on ipv4.

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your routing table is confused. There can only be one default route, not two.

Comment: These are the default settings by the OS, and they have different metrics. I removed the second default gateway `sudo route del default gw OpenWrt.lan` and I have the same problem.